# Get today's total orders count for each product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm looking for a code snippet to get total sales of each product for today, so I can use it in my theme functions.php file.

**Output should be like this (Total Sales Per Item):**

```
Product xxx = 25 orders
Product yyy = 18 orders
Product zzz = 8 orders
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the following very light SQL query and a foreach loop.

That will give you the list of products *(and product variations, but not parent variable products)* of orders count by product for the past 24 hours:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT DISTINCT woim.meta_value as id, COUNT(woi.order_id) as count, woi.order_item_name as name
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON p.ID = woi.order_id
    WHERE p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-on-hold')
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400))
    AND ((woim.meta_key LIKE '_variation_id' AND woim.meta_value > 0)
    OR (woim.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
    AND woim.meta_value NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_parent FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'product_variation')))
    GROUP BY woim.meta_value
" );

// Loop though each product
foreach( $results as $result ){
    $product_id   = $result->id;
    $product_name = $result->name;
    $orders_count = $result->count;
    
    // Formatted Output
    echo 'Product: ' . $product_name .' (' . $product_id . ') = ' . $orders_count . '<br>';
}
```

Tested and works.

---

If you want to get instead the total based on the "today" date, you will replace in the code this line:

```
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400))
```

by this line:

```
AND DATE(p.post_date) >= CURDATE()
```

> **Time zone ajustement** using [`CONVERT_TZ()` SQL function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)
> *(Where you will adjust* `'+10:00'` *the last argument as an offset to match the timezone)*
>
> ```
> AND DATE(p.post_date) >= DATE(CONVERT_TZ( NOW(),'+00:00','+10:00'))
> ```

---

Related similar answers:

- [Get orders total purchases amount for the day in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152861/get-orders-total-purchases-amount-for-the-day-in-woocommerce/51165375#51165375)
- [Total count for each order item in a loop on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314655/total-count-for-each-order-item-in-a-loop-on-woocommerce/51336869#51336869)

Comment: Dear @LoicTheAztec is there any way to choose **AND DATE(p.post_date) >= DATE(NOW())** based on specific time zone? Lets say Pacific Time (PT) or based on WordPress selected Timezone location? Server is located in **CT** but my location is **PT**, how can I do that?

Comment: @tatifox I have added an update at the end, regarding timezone adjustments…