# Woocommerce report show stocks sold by date per product

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I needed some help with a custom query to show no.of products sold by day, and query is being defined with range. So as an example,

Date Range: Feb 01, 2019 - Feb 05, 2019
Products Available: Tshirt, Short

```
Product  Sold Date     Sold    Stocks Left
Tshirt   2019-02-01     5           20
         2019-02-02     2           18
         2019-02-03     0           18
         2019-02-04     1           17
         2019-02-05     2           15

Short    2019-02-01     2           40
         2019-02-02     4           36
         2019-02-03     5           31
         2019-02-04     1           30
         2019-02-05     5           25
```

I have seen this code here: [Get today's total orders count for each product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663249/get-todays-total-orders-count-for-each-product-in-woocommerce)

But the quantity isn't showing, it's only counting the no.of transactions but not the quantity sold.

Thanks in advance gurus.

Comment: Including '-' in table/column identifiers is fantastically dangerous

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand, they're just plainly data. The [product] [sold-date] [stocks-sold] [stock-left] they're just data that's supposedly to be getting from the database. But plainly they're mixed columns of different tables.

To understand completely what I mean with the stocks i needed, here's the picture: https://i.postimg.cc/x174DZW3/52161586-391232491436140-8661295800040554496-n.jpg

Comment: I don't do pictures, unfortunately, but I'm sure others will be able to help.

Comment: Ah I think I understand where the misunderstanding is. Strawberry was basically saying using dashes in table or column names is a bad idea (he's not wrong - it is a bad idea, use underscores instead). But what Hades meant is that its just pseudo-code, and not what the actual columns or tables are called - that's just the data he needs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for so long that I have created my own query, btw i'm using the ATUM Multi Inventory, if you're using that, this might be for you too.

```
$from = strtotime('2019-01-01 00:00:00');
$to = strtotime('2019-02-25 23:59:00');
$branch_request = 'Passi';

$sql = "
    SELECT DISTINCT p.ID as id, woi.order_item_name as name, woi.order_item_id as wid, aio.qty as quantity, p.post_title as title, ai.name as branchname, p.post_date as datesold
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON woi.order_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}atum_inventory_orders as aio ON aio.order_item_id = woi.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}atum_inventories as ai ON ai.id = aio.inventory_id
    WHERE p.post_status = 'wc-completed'
    AND ai.product_id = $product_request
    AND ai.name = '$branch_request'
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) BETWEEN $from AND $to
    ORDER BY p.post_date ASC
";
```

Also for the `$branch_request`, I made a function of that to get all the product id's and `foreach` to show the `product_id` and assigned another `foreach` which inside the `$sql`.