# Woocommerce SQL: printing summerized products where custom field is today

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

How do I get total sales of each product for today, where today is the value of a custom field?

Same kind of solution as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664796/2947684, but using a custom field instead of date.

In this specific situation my custom field is called 'Afhentningsdato', and it is formatted like this: dd-mm-yy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, and I hope other people can use this answer as well.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
  SELECT DISTINCT woim2.meta_value as id, SUM(woim.meta_value) as count, woi.order_item_name as name
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim2 ON woi.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON p.ID = woi.order_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON pm.post_id = woi.order_id
  WHERE p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
  AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_qty'
  AND woim2.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
  AND pm.meta_key LIKE 'Afhentningsdato'
  AND pm.meta_value IN ({$weeksearch})
  GROUP BY woim2.meta_value
  ORDER BY woi.order_item_name
"  );
```

Here I search for a meta value by searching an array (`$weeksearch`) of dates.
To use this for another custom field, simply change 'Afhentningsdato' to another custom field, and change `IN ({$weeksearch})` to your value of choice.